# Capitrano authentication fails with Git bash on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, capistrano, git-bash

I configured capitrano to deploy a Rails app from Git bash on Windows. I created one rsa key to connect to the remote server with the user deploy and another rsa key to connect to bitbucket with my account.

Before deploying I set up the ssh-agent with both keys.

When deploying I have an authentication failed (publickey error) nevertheless when I try to ssh deploy@myserver.com it works and from inside my server if I try git -T git://bitbucket.org it connects and show me my username.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Where is the problem? The first connect to the remote server, or when trying to get code from bitbucket?

Comment: When trying to connect to the server at the beginning of the deploy

Comment: What env on Windows? From DOS cmd? or Cygwin? I'm doing the command from DOS, haven't installed ruby under Cygwin. How have you added the ssh-key? I'm using Putty and Pageant, it's working good. If you do a ssh to the server, what happens?

Comment: In using the bash provided by Git. Ssh keys are in ~/.ssh and in the ssh agent. When sshing to the server it connects

Comment: And you do the cap command from git bash? Can you add output from screen and cap log?

Comment: The issue was solved using pageant instead of ssh-agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the ssh client used by capitrano doesn't handle ssh-agent on Windows. The solution was to use Pageant the agent of the putty project but before importing keys to pageant they have to be converted to the ppk format by puttykeygen